# Is passing an r-value to functions returning it considered wrong in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function `Service` that energize an exhausted phone   and return it as follows.

[image]

Writing

```
Phone p;
p = Service(p);
```

does not look elegant so I want to write as follows.

```
Phone& p = Service(Phone());
```

Doing so produces weird outputs as follows.

```
Ctor
Dtor
Destroyed
Energy: 100%
Ending...
```

The expected output is:

```
Ctor
Energy: 100%
Dtor
Destroyed
Ending...
```

## Question

Could you tell me why this happens?

**Note:** I am new to C++.

```
class Phone
{
private:
    int energy;
    bool destroyed = false;
public:
    Phone() : energy{ 0 } {
        cout << "Ctor" << endl;
    }
    ~Phone()
    {
        cout << "Dtor" << endl;
        if (destroyed == false)
        {
            cout << "Destroyed..." << endl;
            destroyed = true;
        }
    }

    void Energize() { energy = 100; }
    void Status() const
    {
        cout << "Energy: " << energy << "%" << endl;
    }
};


Phone& Service(Phone&& input)
{
    input.Energize();
    return input;
}


int main()
{
    Phone& p = Service(Phone());
    p.Status();

    cout << "Ending..." << endl;
}
```

Comment: The `const Button& b = ButtonHole(Button());` temporary button is destructed at the end of the statement.  A const-reference lifetime extension is not transitive through the in parameter and out the return value.

Comment: `ButtonHole(Button()).PassThrough();` will work. Perhaps not in the exact way you expect, but at least without undefined behavior.

Comment: Add logging for copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators, that will give you a better picture of what is actually happening

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to return a copy of the phone. So just pass it as reference and operate on it:

```
void Service(Phone& phone);
```

```
Phone p{};

Service(p);
```

Comment: So it means that C++ does not have such a feature which is available in C#? In C# we can write `Phone p = Auxiliary.Service(new Phone());`.

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage first: try not to write C++ like C#. Second: I don't understand: what feature? Ofc you can design something similar, but keep in mind: in C# classes are references, so you are not passing around objects.